# How can i set data in state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, maps

Since i am new in react,i used filter and map to select array from array list.I got my output as expected.Now i want to set this.state.search by rendered value.How can i do it?
Here are the pictures of my code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NativeSelect } from '@material-ui/core';

export default class Test extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        people: [
            {
                address: "Biratnagar",

                bank: "Nabil Bank",

                bankaccountnumber: 34343434,

                baselocation: "Kathmandu",

                basicpay: 5000,

                branch: "telecom",

                class: "class1",

                confirmpassword: "nabanit123",

                degree: "master",

                designation: "engineer",

                email: "nabanitkoirala@gmail.com",

                id: "5e9fdebf0178920ed082241f",

                mobilenumber: 445454545,

                name: "Nabanit Koirala",

                password: "nabanit123",

                salary: 20000
            },
            {
                address: "Biratnagar",

                bank: "Nabil Bank",

                bankaccountnumber: 34343434,

                baselocation: "Kathmandu",

                basicpay: 5000,

                branch: "telecom",

                class: "class1",

                confirmpassword: "nabanit123",

                degree: "master",

                designation: "engineer",

                email: "nabanitkoirala@gmail.com",

                id: "5e9fdebf0178920ed082241f",

                mobilenumber: 445454545,

                name: "saroj kumar",

                password: "nabanit123",

                salary: 30000
            },
            {
                address: "Biratnagar",

                bank: "Nabil Bank",

                bankaccountnumber: 34343434,

                baselocation: "Kathmandu",

                basicpay: 5000,

                branch: "Account",

                class: "class1",

                confirmpassword: "nabanit123",

                degree: "master",

                designation: "engineer",

                email: "nabanitkoirala@gmail.com",

                id: "5e9fdebf0178920ed082241f",

                mobilenumber: 445454545,

                name: "kamlesh shresths",

                password: "nabanit123",

                salary: 5000
            },
            {
                address: "Biratnagar",

                bank: "Nabil Bank",

                bankaccountnumber: 34343434,

                baselocation: "Kathmandu",

                basicpay: 5000,

                branch: "IT",

                class: "class1",

                confirmpassword: "nabanit123",

                degree: "master",

                designation: "engineer",

                email: "nabanitkoirala@gmail.com",

                id: "5e9fdebf0178920ed082241f",

                mobilenumber: 445454545,

                name: "kumar thapa",

                password: "nabanit123",

                salary: 50000
            },
        ],
        name: '',
        isLoading: true,
        search: ''
    }
}
handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    })
}
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
        isLoading: false


    })

    console.log("handle submit>>", this.state);
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        search: Test
    })

}

render() {
    console.log("component did mount>>", this.state);
    const { search } = this.state;
    let Test = this.state.isLoading
        ? <p>Isloading</p>
        : this.state.people.filter(item => item.name === this.state.name).map(item => (
            <div>
                <p>key:{item.name}</p>
                <div>

                    <p>add:{item.address}</p>
                    <p>bank:{item.bank}</p>
                    <p>bankaccount:{item.bankaccountnumber}</p>
                    <p>baselocation:{item.baselocation}</p>
                    <p>basicpay:{item.basicpay}</p>
                    <p>branch:{item.branch}</p>
                    <p>class:{item.class}</p>
                    <p>confirmpassword:{item.confirmpassword}</p>
                    <p>degree:{item.degree}</p>
                    <p>designation:{item.designation}</p>
                    <p>email:{item.email}</p>
                    <p>mobilenumber:{item.mobilenumber}</p>
                    <p>name:{item.name}</p>
                    <p>password:{item.password}</p>
                    <p>salary:{item.salary}</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        ))
    this.state.search = Test;
    return (
        <div>


            <NativeSelect defaultValue="" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="choose">choose</option>
                <option value="Nabanit Koirala">Nabanit Koirala</option>
                <option value="Saroj Kumar">Saroj Kumar</option>

            </NativeSelect>
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Search</button>
            <div>
                {Test}

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Since i get the output value,the array stored in state is filtered and displayed in the browser,now i want to store the filtered array in state,so how can i do it now.

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Comment: In Your return statement you are using {Test}. instead of it create one arrow function and do all the code for filtering there and call that function. You can also set your state in that function.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the question, but I wanted to point out that `this.state.search = Test;` is not the way to update the state. If you'd like to update the component's state, you should always use `setState`: `this.setState({search: Test})`. Also, the `render` method should not contain state update logic (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a separate state for `filteredPeople` and update it in your `handleChange`. While rendering, just map through `filteredPeople`.

**See the snippet:**

```js
this.state = {
        people: [
            {
                address: "Biratnagar",
            ...
            }
        name,
        filteredPeople=[],   
        ...

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value,
        filteredPeople: this.state.people.filter(item => item[name] === value)
    })
       ...
let Test = this.state.isLoading
        ? <p>Isloading</p>
        : this.state.filteredPeople.map(item => (
            <div>
                <p>key:
        ... 

}
```

Also, make sure to provide a `value` i.e.`this.state.name` to `<NativeSelect>` as it is a controlled field.

```js
<NativeSelect defaultValue="" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="choose">choose</option>
```

Comment: awesome .. you can please consider to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you're updating the state in the wrong way in your `render` method:

```
// No-op
this.state.search = Test; 
// Correct way should be
this.setState({ search: Test });
```

Secondly, I think your idea of storing the rendered node into the state isn't the way to go. You should probably store the filtered array result in the state, and then let the `render` method do its job to render the result out.

```
const Test = <div>{this.state.people.map(item => <p>{item}</p>)}</div>;

this.setState({ search: Test }); // Don't do this
```

---

What you want is maybe:

Add a new array in your state to store the result (instead of calling `search` maybe good to rename it to `result`). This is so that you can keep the original `people` state to use later for filtering:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      people: SAMPLE_DATA,
      name: "", // Maybe you don't need to store this?
      result: []
    };
}
```

in your `handleChange` event handler, update the filtered value into the state:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState(prev => ({
      [name]: value,
      // You got the value now, so update the result at the same time
      result: prev.people.filter(item => item.name === value),
    }));
}
```

And in your `render` method, you can render it out directly:

```
render() {
    const { result } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <NativeSelect defaultValue="" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="choose">choose</option>
          <option value="Nabanit Koirala">Nabanit Koirala</option>
          <option value="Saroj Kumar">Saroj Kumar</option>
        </NativeSelect>

        <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Search</button>
        <div>
          {
            result.map(item => (
              <div key={item.name}>
                <p>key:{item.name}</p>
                <div>
                  <p>add:{item.address}</p>
                  <p>bank:{item.bank}</p>
                  <p>bankaccount:{item.bankaccountnumber}</p>
                  <p>baselocation:{item.baselocation}</p>
                  <p>basicpay:{item.basicpay}</p>
                  <p>branch:{item.branch}</p>
                  <p>class:{item.class}</p>
                  <p>confirmpassword:{item.confirmpassword}</p>
                  <p>degree:{item.degree}</p>
                  <p>designation:{item.designation}</p>
                  <p>email:{item.email}</p>
                  <p>mobilenumber:{item.mobilenumber}</p>
                  <p>name:{item.name}</p>
                  <p>password:{item.password}</p>
                  <p>salary:{item.salary}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit fragrant-glitter-xrw7o]

> Tips: if you want to compare names, maybe consider comparing them in lowercase. Unless you want to compare exactly the same.

```
this.setState(prev => ({
  [name]: value,
  result: prev.people.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase())
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can just Modify the handleChange()

And remove this line  `this.state.search = Test` from your code because updating state in a render() is not a right way.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    })
      var searchedResult=  this.state.people.filter(item => item.name === this.state.name);

       this.setState({
        search: searchedResult
       })
       console.log('searched data =>',this.state.search);
}
```

---

**✅Final result**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NativeSelect } from '@material-ui/core';

export default class Test extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        people: [
            {
                address: "Biratnagar",

                bank: "Nabil Bank",

                bankaccountnumber: 34343434,

                baselocation: "Kathmandu",

                basicpay: 5000,

                branch: "telecom",

                class: "class1",

                confirmpassword: "nabanit123",

                degree: "master",

                designation: "engineer",

                email: "nabanitkoirala@gmail.com",

                id: "5e9fdebf0178920ed082241f",

                mobilenumber: 445454545,

                name: "Nabanit Koirala",

                password: "nabanit123",

                salary: 20000
            },
            {
                address: "Biratnagar",

                bank: "Nabil Bank",

                bankaccountnumber: 34343434,

                baselocation: "Kathmandu",

                basicpay: 5000,

                branch: "telecom",

                class: "class1",

                confirmpassword: "nabanit123",

                degree: "master",

                designation: "engineer",

                email: "nabanitkoirala@gmail.com",

                id: "5e9fdebf0178920ed082241f",

                mobilenumber: 445454545,

                name: "saroj kumar",

                password: "nabanit123",

                salary: 30000
            },
            {
                address: "Biratnagar",

                bank: "Nabil Bank",

                bankaccountnumber: 34343434,

                baselocation: "Kathmandu",

                basicpay: 5000,

                branch: "Account",

                class: "class1",

                confirmpassword: "nabanit123",

                degree: "master",

                designation: "engineer",

                email: "nabanitkoirala@gmail.com",

                id: "5e9fdebf0178920ed082241f",

                mobilenumber: 445454545,

                name: "kamlesh shresths",

                password: "nabanit123",

                salary: 5000
            },
            {
                address: "Biratnagar",

                bank: "Nabil Bank",

                bankaccountnumber: 34343434,

                baselocation: "Kathmandu",

                basicpay: 5000,

                branch: "IT",

                class: "class1",

                confirmpassword: "nabanit123",

                degree: "master",

                designation: "engineer",

                email: "nabanitkoirala@gmail.com",

                id: "5e9fdebf0178920ed082241f",

                mobilenumber: 445454545,

                name: "kumar thapa",

                password: "nabanit123",

                salary: 50000
            },
        ],
        name: '',
        isLoading: true,
        search: ''
    }
}
    handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
          var searchedResult=  this.state.people.filter(item => item.name === this.state.name);

           this.setState({
            search: searchedResult
           })
           console.log('searched data =>',this.state.search);
    }
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
        isLoading: false


    })

    console.log("handle submit>>", this.state);
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        search: Test
    })

}

render() {
    console.log("component did mount>>", this.state);
    const { search } = this.state;
    let Test = this.state.isLoading
        ? <p>Isloading</p>
        : this.state.people.filter(item => item.name === this.state.name).map(item => (
            <div>
                <p>key:{item.name}</p>
                <div>

                    <p>add:{item.address}</p>
                    <p>bank:{item.bank}</p>
                    <p>bankaccount:{item.bankaccountnumber}</p>
                    <p>baselocation:{item.baselocation}</p>
                    <p>basicpay:{item.basicpay}</p>
                    <p>branch:{item.branch}</p>
                    <p>class:{item.class}</p>
                    <p>confirmpassword:{item.confirmpassword}</p>
                    <p>degree:{item.degree}</p>
                    <p>designation:{item.designation}</p>
                    <p>email:{item.email}</p>
                    <p>mobilenumber:{item.mobilenumber}</p>
                    <p>name:{item.name}</p>
                    <p>password:{item.password}</p>
                    <p>salary:{item.salary}</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        ))
    // this.state.search = Test;// Do not do like this
    return (
        <div>


            <NativeSelect defaultValue="" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="choose">choose</option>
                <option value="Nabanit Koirala">Nabanit Koirala</option>
                <option value="Saroj Kumar">Saroj Kumar</option>

            </NativeSelect>
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Search</button>
            <div>
                {Test}

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```